# Keeping label on two lines starting from the same point?

Tags: html, css

How can I keep a label and it's text starting on the same place?
For example, what I want to achieve:

☑️ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
     consectetur adipiscing elit.

And here is my attempt:

```css
div {
  width:300px;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at     molestie mi.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` from CSS like so:

```css
div {
  width:300px;
}
/* lines I added */
label{
 display: flex;
 align-items:flex-start;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    /* line I added */
    flex:none;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at     molestie mi.</label>
</div>
```